# Gradle sync failed: Illegal Capacity: -182931123

Tags: gradle

I only open simple project and recieve error `"Gradle sync failed: Illegal Capacity: -182931123"`

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It seems that deleting `/home/<user>/.gradle/daemon/4.1/registry.bin` and `/home/<user>/.gradle/daemon/4.1/registry.bin.lock` solved in my case.

I just upgraded Android Studio to 3.0 and gradle accordingly, on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: clearing both files from gradle daemon version folders solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Intesresting... any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting

- `/home/<user>/.gradle/daemon/<version>/registry.bin`
- `/home/<user>/.gradle/daemon/<version>/registry.bin.lock`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but:

1. Create New Project and close it
2. delete app module from new project
3. copy app module from old project which is showing error
4. past app module to new project directory
5. open project and Sync from file menu